# Python: Trying to access hour, minute, second in a datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm quite new to the Python environment. I'm trying to modify a datetime object using the method replace(hour=...,minute=...,second=...) iterativly and saving the results at each recursion in a pd.Series. The goal is to have a pd.Series with different datetime objects for each row (with the same y, m, d but different h, mm, ss)

I started by creating a datetime object and then by setting-up a for loop in which hour, minute and second are calculated and then assigned to an already created datetime object. So the result would be a different date (in terms of h, m, s) for each iteration.\

This is something similar to what I've written:

```py
    import datetime as dt

    Today = dt.datetime.now()
    Dates = pd.Series([])

    for i in range(0, 20):
        h = # a positive integer 1:24
        m = # a positive integer 0:59
        s = # a positive integer 0:59

        Date = [Today][0]    # to avoid Date being referenced to Today

        Date.replace(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)

        Dates[i] = [Date][0]
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that Dates rows do have the same date (with the same h, m, s), but I need to have different dates in each Dates rows. I think it might be a reference issue but I'm not sure how to deal whit this (I guess that a "copy method" would be the solution but datetime object do not have such a method).

Does anybody have some suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, your `[...][0]` basically does nothing. You put something into a list and then take it out again, which does exactly zilch.

Comment: `datetime.replace` ***returns a new `datetime` instance*** with the changed values. It doesn't modify the existing instance…

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by avoiding date referencing today? Can you give an example of what you want these dates to be given that your first call is to .now()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python the general rule is to use `snake_case` for variable names and `PascalCase` for classes.

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you want something like timedelta.

Here's a complete working example of what I think you're after:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

today = dt.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
dates = pd.Series([])

for i in range(0, 20):
    h = 1 # a positive integer 1:24
    m = 1 # a positive integer 0:59
    s = 1 # a positive integer 0:59

    dates[i] = today + dt.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)

print(dates)
```

Comment: It’s not the best of general rules though ... within your example both `datetime` and `timedelta` are types/classes ... they’re neither `snake_case` nor `CamelCase` ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the hour/minute/second in a already declared datetime object, directly access it by '.'

i.e.

```
date = datetime.now()
date.hour
```

Output:

```
16
```

If you want to make a new datetime object with specific hour/minute/second, use replace()